# ListView for Django not Working but function based view is working

Tags: django, django-views

When I am using function based view using the following code:

from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView

```
from .models import Restaurant
def restaurant_listview(request):
    template = 'restaurants/restaurants_list.html'
    context = {
    "queryset" : Restaurant.objects.order_by('-updated')
    }
    return render (request, template, context)
```

it is working with the url file kept as  follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from restaurants import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^restaurants/$', views.restaurant_listview),
]
```

But when I am trying to do the same thing with class based views it is not working only the following portion doesn't seem to work:

```
<ul>
  {% for obj in queryset %}
  <li>{{obj.name}}, {{obj.location}}, {{obj.category}}, {{obj.timestamp}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

the following part works fine:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Restaurants List {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Restaurants</h1>
```

for class based view my views.py is:

```
class RestaurantListView(ListView):
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
    template_name = 'restaurants/restaurants_list.html'
```

and urls.py is:

```
url(r'^restaurants$', RestaurantListView.as_view(), name='Home')
```

P.S. I am following this guide : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDv5FIAeyoY&t=25471s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a list view, you should change the template to:

```
{% for obj in restaurant_list %}
```

Or, if you really want to use the variable `queryset` in the template, then set `context_object_name`.

```
class RestaurantListView(ListView):
     queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
     template_name = 'restaurants/restaurants_list.html'
     context_object_name = 'queryset'
```